# How to build for iOS while target includes a Mac-only package?

Tags: swift, xcode, sparkle

I am trying to build a multi-platform app and have used the `Sparkle` framework in the project for the macOS platform. However, Xcode is giving me the error `While building for iOS, no library for this platform was found in '.../Sparkle.xcframework'`, even though I have marked Sparkle as for macOS in the `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content` section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Targets >> Build phases >> Link Binary with Libraries >> Sparkle
- You have to change platform like this

[You have to try this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMIBn.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34501521)